# Comparing two numbers in JavaScript, what about the fact those are doubles and the use of == or ===?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, comparison

When I write code in JavaScript, I rarely think about the consequence of using the == or === operators while comparing numbers. However, JavaScript numbers are double's and as such the == and === should never be used as is.

From the documentation on comparing two numbers with === we get:

> 11.9.6 The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm
>
> The comparison x === y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.
> 2. If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.
> 3. If Type(x) is Null, return true.
> 4. If Type(x) is Number, then
>
>    > a. If x is NaN, return false.
>    >
>    > b. If y is NaN, return false.
>    >
>    > c. If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
>    >
>    > d. If x is +0 and y is -0, return true.
>    >
>    > e. If x is -0 and y is +0, return true.
>    >
>    > f. Return false.
> 5. If Type(x) is String, then return true if x and y are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in corresponding positions); otherwise, return false.
> 6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return true if x and y are both true or both false; otherwise, return false.
> 7. Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.
>
> NOTE
>   This algorithm differs from the SameValue Algorithm (9.12) in its treatment of signed zeroes and NaNs.

The non strict == operator has the same algorithm when it comes to comparing two numbers (4.a to 4.f), only it allows for the conversion of strings to a number.

So... is the language intrinsically testing floating points *with a certain precision* or do they use the plain good old == as found in C/C++ and other languages?

```
var a = 1.23;
    b = 1.230000001;

if(a === b) alert("equal?!");
```

This code does not produce the alert which would mean that it works as in C/C++.

Comment: It is rarely *ever* valid to test floating point numbers for equality (zero being an exception).

Comment: Floating point equality is a bit-for-bit comparison, whether you're doing it with `==` or `===`.  Really, your question isn't super clear here. (The +/- zero case is clearly an exception to the bit-for-bit thing, but that's just one bit :)

Comment: If you want to compare two floats for equality in javascript (or even in C++), you pretty have to round it to a specific precision and if they are the same type, it makes no difference whether you use `==` or `===`.

Comment: My question is about numbers in general. In JavaScript, we all do stuff such as `if(counter == 5) ...` yet counter is a `double` (internally). So I was wondering whether there was some heuristic in JavaScript to make sure such tests work as expected.

Comment: What about using `if(parseInt(counter, 10) === 5)`?

Comment: @Shakeel, `parseInt()`, internally, still returns a double. But, yes, that would help clean up the value of counter. You could also make use of the `Math.floor()/ceil()/rount()` functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you found, `==` and `===` behave identically if both types are numbers.

When comparing numbers for equality, JavaScript obeys the IEEE 754 standard. For most purposes, this is no different than C's `double` type. It means JavaScript will **not** do any precision checks for you. When needed, you write your own code to handle precision loss.

---

That answers your question, but there is one very common misconception you brought up!

> JavaScript numbers are double's and as such the == and === should never be used as is.

The actual math behind this is a bit more complicated. Once grasped, you get some leeway with precision checks.

Consider the following which are **guaranteed truths**:

```
5 + 6 === 11
3 + 0.5 === 3.5
1.1 + 1 === 2.1
1.230000001 === 1.230000001
40 / 2 === 20
-0 === +0
```

But still, the following could be true or false **depending on precision**:

```
1.23 === 1.230000001
1.1 + 0.1 === 1.2
11 / 10 * 11 === 11 * 11 / 10
```

To make dealing with doubles easier, these conditions will not cause a loss of precision for a large range of floating-point numbers:

- Adding, subtracting and multiplying doubles without a fractional part
- Dividing doubles without a fractional part and that are divisible
- Adding together doubles which are represented as a fraction of denominator 2, 4, 8, 16, ...
- Multiplying any double by 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 4, -4, 8, -8, ...
- Dividing any double by 1, -1, 2, -2, 4, -4, 8, -8, ...

Finally, if you want to know more about floating-point math, this article is heavily referenced (but may go into too much detail for your needs): [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Ah! I see... `4.3.19 Number value -- primitive value corresponding to a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value` So all the math corresponds one to one to C/C++. Only when you use integers, and there are enough bits in the mantissa, you're good with `==/===`

Comment: @AlexisWilke Yes exactly! There may be some subtle differences like signalling NaN, but everything you'd care about functions identically to a C/C++ `double` using IEEE 754.

Comment: Anyhow, it is really important to understand these universal software concepts. Improper floating-point math was the root cause of a tragic software accident regarding the Patriot anti-missile system. A brief video is at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMVBLg2MrLs&feature=player_detailpage#t=137

Comment: YouTube forbids that video in the US it looks like... Americans do not like to be told something of theirs failed, ever.